# What is the python/numpy equivalent of num2cell()?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I'm unlucky enough to be converting some MATLAB code into Python via numpy arrays.

Is there any consensus on `num2cell()`?

Personally, I think this goes against Python/numpy syntax. The idea is this:

Using `num2cell`, you'll end up in an array that looks like this

`array([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]])`

See [the MathWorks documentaiton](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html).

You could do this in numpy with a list comprehension:

```
matlab_lunacy = np.array([[x] for x in range(0, 9)]
```

But why do MATLAB users use this data structure?

What's the numpy equivalent?

Comment: `num2cell()` is very useful for partitioning data. It allows you to easily slice up any multi-D array into sections, facilitating subsequent manipulation. You can slice it up so that you have a list of rows, a list of columns, etc., or even a list of arbitrary blocks.

Comment: Cells in MATLAB are usually used for non-regular (non-matrix-like) data structures, e.g. sequence of vectors of different sizes or sequence of strings. Python's equivalent would be a native list (or dict) of objects.

Comment: So did any of our answers help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the good old days (around v. 3.0) MATLAB had only one data structure, a matrix.  It could contain numbers or characters, and was always 2d.

Cells were added to contain more general objects, including matrices and strings.  They were still 2d.

Python had lists, which are 1d, but can contain anything.  `numpy` is built on Python, adding the multidimensional arrays.  But lists are still available.

So potentially anything that converts an array to a list is an equivalent to `num2cell` - not exact, but with overlapping functionality.

```
In [246]: A=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)   # 3d array
```

Wrapping in a list, gives us a list of 2 arrays (2d):

```
In [247]: B=list(A)
In [248]: B
Out[248]: 
[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]), 
 array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]])]
```

`tolist` method performs complete conversion to lists (nested).

```
In [249]: C=A.tolist()
In [250]: C
Out[250]: 
[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]],
 [[12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]
```

`list(A)` is not common, and may be used in error when `tolist` is meant.

`np.split(A,...)` is similar to `B`, but the subarrays are still 3d.

`unpacking` even works, basically because `A` is an iterable, `[a for a in A]` splits `A` on the 1st dimension.

```
In [257]: a,b=A
In [258]: a
Out[258]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

There is an object dtype, with lets you put objects, including other arrays, in an array.  But as has been shown in many SO questions, these can be tricky to construct.  `np.array` tries to construct the highest dimension array possible.  You have to perform some tricks to get around that.

```
In [259]: Z=np.empty((2,),dtype=object)
In [260]: Z
Out[260]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [261]: Z[0]=A[0]
In [262]: Z[1]=A[1]
In [263]: Z
Out[263]: 
array([ array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]),
       array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])], dtype=object)
```

================

In an Octave session:

```
>> anum = [1,2,3,4]
anum =

   1   2   3   4

>> acell = num2cell(anum)
acell =
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [1,2] =  2
  [1,3] =  3
  [1,4] =  4
}
>> save -7 test.mat anum acell
```

the `scipy.io.loatmat` version

```
In [1822]: data = io.loadmat('../test.mat')
In [1823]: data
Out[1823]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 
     2016-10-27 00:59:27 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'acell': array([[array([[ 1.]]), array([[ 2.]]), array([[ 3.]]),
      array([[ 4.]])]], dtype=object),
 'anum': array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]])}
```

The `matrix` is rendered as a 2d array;  the `cell` as an object type array (2d), containing, in this case, 2d arrays.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know `tolist` existed.  Beats my recursive implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`num2cell` essentially takes each element in an array and presents it as individual cells in a cell matrix.  The Python equivalent to a cell array is a list.  Therefore, if you really wanted to create a `num2cell` equivalent in Python, you would create a list that has the same dimensions as your Python NumPy array and ensure that each element in this list goes in the right location.  Something like this would work:

```
import numpy as np

def num2cell(a):
    if type(a) is np.ndarray:
        return [num2cell(x) for x in a]
    else:
        return a
```

This **recursively** goes through each dimension of your NumPy array.  For each element in a dimension in this array, if the element is also an array, then for each element in the next dimension, convert into a list representation.  The base case is when we actually hit an actual number and if that's the case, just return the actual number.

Here's a working example after defining `num2cell` in my Python workspace:

```
In [26]: import numpy as np

In [27]: A = np.random.rand(4,3,3)

In [28]: B = num2cell(A)

In [29]: A[0]
Out[29]:
array([[ 0.52971132,  0.91969837,  0.77649566],
       [ 0.51080951,  0.8086879 ,  0.61840573],
       [ 0.7291165 ,  0.0492292 ,  0.53997368]])

In [30]: B[0]
Out[30]:
[[0.52971132352406691, 0.91969837282865874, 0.77649565991300817],
 [0.51080951338602765, 0.80868789862631529, 0.61840573261134801],
 [0.72911649507775378, 0.049229201932639577, 0.53997367763478676]]

In [31]: A[1][1]
Out[31]: array([ 0.41724412,  0.94679946,  0.79899245])

In [32]: B[1][1]
Out[32]: [0.41724411973558406, 0.9467994633124529, 0.7989924496851234]
```

We can see here that `B` is list representation of the NumPy array `A`.

Comment: `A.tolist()` will give you an almost identical result to `num2cell(A)`, the only difference being that each element will be a native Python `float` rather than an `np.float64`.

Comment: @ali_m I realize that. I left a comment in hpaulj's post.  It basically says that I didn't know that `tolist()` exists :)

Comment: @ali_m Not at all. I should probably edit my post to reflect that. I do appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the rest of the code is doing. Generally speaking Matlab uses cells to represent an array of arrays, where the inner arrays can have different sizes and shapes.

To answer your question though, I think that what you've done is basically what you want to do, i.e. create an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`.astype(np.object_)` is most likely the thing you need. Consider this matlab code:

```
x = [1 2 3 4]
y = num2cell(x)
y(end) = 'hello'
```

In numpy, that translates to:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = x.astype(np.object_)
y[-1] = 'hello'
```

Answer (score -2):

A completely different route to take is to use matlabs python interface, which allows you to call the matlab engine and thereby also matlab codes from python. See https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: The setup is quite hairy, as you have to link the libraries to each other, but the guides are quite well written. Once you have it installed it is as simple as importing it `import matlab.engine` and defining it `eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()` and now you can call your own matlab functions e.g. `result = eng.YourFunction(inputs)`

Comment: This interface is designed to communicate between MATLAB and Python, so valid MATLAB licence and MATLAB server started still is required. Usually code would be ported e.g. when you do not have money for MATLAB licence. If you have, you'd just run original code.