# How can I translate a MATLAB cell in Python 3?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

*Just to give you some context:*

I have to translate some MATLAB code into Python 3 one, but here I've been confronted to a little problem.

Matlab:

```
for i in 1:num_nodes
    for j in 1:num_nodes
        K{i,j} = zeros(3,3);
```

Which I translated into:

```
k_topology = [[]]
for i in range(x):
    for i in range(x):
        k_topology[[i][j]].extend(np.zeros(3,3))
```

Also, further in the Matlab code there's a third loop:

```
for k in 1:3
    K{i,j}(k,k) = -1
```

Which also kind of... Upsets me?

The fact is I don't really see how I can translate this kind of variable into Python. Also, I guess that my Python code's kind of "broken" - *and I'm not really asking to any of you to improve it* - , so I'm just asking **which is the best way to translate Matlab's cell into Python?**

---

I finally found something *apparently* simple to translate this, using list comprehension - *according to kazemakase's answer*. The actual Python code is now looking like this:

```
k_topology = [[np.zeros((3,3)) for j in range(self.get_nb_nodes_from_network())]\
                  for i in range(self.get_nb_nodes_from_network())]
```

And looks like something like this in Output:

```
[[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])], ..., [array(...)]]
```

(There's really too many values to paste it here, but I think you got it.)

Comment: It may he helpful to describe what that Matlab code does, and why you think it will be difficult to translate.

Comment: Well the K matrix is meant to represent the topology of an electrical network. So it will contain other matrices with length from 1 to 3 max. As far as it gets, I can understand the first loop (the one with the K{i,j}), but the second seems to me really weird: What is the K{i,j}(k,k)? How can I translate it? That's why I find it difficult: I just don't understand that

Comment: So `K` is two-dimensional? What's the difference then between `k_topology` and `K`?

Comment: I think the closest would be `np.array` of `dtype=object`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that: k_topology is my Python equivalent to the Matlab's K matrix

Comment: The `K{i,j}(k,k)` loop is just setting the diagonals of all the matrices that were initialized. I don't really see any issue with the Python array of arrays translation, that's all MATLAB's cell array is enabling, though I would suggest denesting the Python array (e.g. MATLAB's `K{i, j}` returns a `3x3` array, so Python's `k_topology[i, j]` should also return a `3x3` array).

Comment: er...`k_topology[i][j]`

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266943/what-is-the-python-numpy-equivalent-of-num2cell) has a few ideas on how to translate cells to numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question you need to ask is "what *is* a Matlab cell and what could be a suitable corresponding Python type?"

If I remember correctly from my bad old Matlab days, a cell is sort of a container that holds content of mixed types. It is something like a dynamically typed array or matrix. It is multidimensionally indexed.

Python is dynamically typed, so any Python contianer can basically fulfill this function. Lists in Python are indexed, so nested lists could work - but they are somewhat weird to set up and access:

```
K = [[None] * num_nodes  for _ in range(num_nodes)]
K[i][j]  # need two indices to access elements of a nested list.
```

For the particular scenario a dictionary better mirrors Matlab syntax. Although a ditionary takes only one index, we can exploit the fact that tuples can be declared without brackets and that dictionaries can take tuples as index:

```
K = {}
for i in range(num_nodes):
    for j in range(num_nodes):
        K[i, j] = np.zeros((3, 3))

        for k in 1:3
            K[i, j][k, k] = -1
```

While the dictionary is syntactically more concise, element access is potentially less performant than in nested lists. Nested look different than Matlab code. The choice depends on performance or similarity to the original code. But if performance is an issue there are many more things to consider, anyway. In summary: **There is no one best way to do it.**

---

Since the OP expclicitly asked not to improve the code, I explicitly ask him/her to ignore this part of the answer.

A better way to build diagonal matrices is to use `np.ones` instead of looping over diagonal elements.

```
K = {}
for i in range(num_nodes):
    for j in range(num_nodes):
        K[i, j] = -np.ones((3, 3))
```

Also, nested lists can be constructed without (much) prior initialization, if that is the preferred approach:

```
K = []
for i in range(num_nodes):
    K.append([])
    for j in range(num_nodes):
        K[-1].append(-np.ones((3, 3)))
```

---

Now, for the peace of my soul, let me <s>take apart</s> provide feedback on the OP's code:

> ```
> k_topology = [[]]
> for i in range(x):
>     for i in range(x):
>         k_topology[[i][j]].extend(np.zeros(3,3))
> ```

1. This has nothing to do with the original Matlab code (different variable names)
2. Both loops use `i`. `j` is never defined.
3. `[[i][j]]` builds a list with one element `i` and tries to take the jth element. If `j` is ever something other than 0 this will cause an error.
4. `list.extend` a appends all elements of the argument individually to the list - in this case individual rows. `list.append` would be correct to use as the whole 3x3 matrix should be appended as one element in K.
5. `np.zeros(3, 3)` should be `np.zeros((3, 3))` (assuming `np` is an alias for `numpy`) because the function takes the shape is the first argument, not multiple arguments.

Comment: Well, thanks for that answer, that clarified things a lot to me! So I guess I am going to check for the one involving nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Octave/scipy save/loadmat that I demonstrated in the linked post:

In an Octave session

```
>> num_nodes=3
num_nodes =  3
>> num_nodes=3;
>> K=cell(num_nodes, num_nodes);
>> for i = 1:num_nodes
   for j = 1:num_nodes
      K{i,j} = zeros(2,2);
   end
end

>> K
K =
{
  [1,1] =

     0   0
     0   0

  [2,1] =

     0   0
     0   0
etc
```

Access one cell:

```
>> K{1,2}
ans =

   0   0
   0   0
```

Access one element of one cell:

```
>> K{1,2}(1,1)
ans = 0

>> save -7 kfile.mat K
```

In Python

```
In [31]: from scipy import io
In [32]: data = io.loadmat('kfile.mat')
In [34]: data
Out[34]: 
{'K': array([[array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]),
         array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]),
         array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]])],
        [array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]),
         array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]),
         array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]])],
        [array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]),
         array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]),
         array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]])]], dtype=object),
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 2017-02-15 19:05:44 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0'}

In [35]: data['K'].shape
Out[35]: (3, 3)
In [36]: data['K'][0,0].shape
Out[36]: (2, 2)
In [37]: data['K'][0,0][0,0]
Out[37]: 0.0
```

`loadmat` treats a `cell` as a 2d object dtype array; while regular matrices are 2d numeric arrays.  Object arrays are, in many ways like a nested Python list.

Comment: Thanks. I finally used list comprehension to solve my problem, but I am not using Octave, so I don't think your answer is relevant to my problem

Comment: Octave is Matlab compatible.  I was illustrating the most direct equivalence between the Matlab structures and numpy ones.  But it is somewhat awkward to create a 2d object array directly, and in your case probably not needed.  Lists are more natural/native in python.